# How to trace "failwith" error in Emacs?

Tags: debugging, emacs, ocaml

I am writing OCaml under Emacs. I have already configured Emacs so that `Meta-x compile` and `make -k` gives warnings with hyperlink. But for errors raised by `failwith`, it can not give a hyperlink, for instance:

```
analyzing (ZONE)...
Fatal error: exception Failure("to do")
Raised at file "pervasives.ml", line 22, characters 22-33
Called from file "list.ml", line 69, characters 12-15
make: *** [all] Error 2

Compilation exited abnormally with code 2 at Fri Jan 27 18:44:10
```

I have many `failwith "to do"` in my code, and need to know which one raises the error, does anyone know how to let Emacs locate this kind of error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [following bug report](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=5044) for some elisp to add to your .emacs, so that the compilation major mode knows how to parse OCaml backtrace reports.

Here is the suggested code (plus tuareg-mode hooks):

```
(defun caml-change-error-alist-for-backtraces ()
  "Hook to change the compilation-error-regexp-alist variable, to
   search the ocaml backtraces for error locations"
  (interactive)
  (progn
    (setq compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist
          (append
           '((caml-backtrace
"^ *\\(?:Raised at\\|Called from\\) file \\(\"?\\)\\([^,\" \n\t<>]+\\)\\1,\
 lines? \\([0-9]+\\)-?\\([0-9]+\\)?\\(?:$\\|,\
\\(?: characters? \\([0-9]+\\)-?\\([0-9]+\\)?:?\\)?\\)"
              2 (3 . 4) (5 . 6)))
           compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist))
    (setq compilation-error-regexp-alist
          (append compilation-error-regexp-alist '(caml-backtrace)))))

(add-hook 'caml-mode-hook 'caml-change-error-alist-for-backtraces)
(add-hook 'tuareg-mode-hook 'caml-change-error-alist-for-backtraces)


(defun caml-change-error-alist-for-assert-failure ()
  "Hook to change the compilation-error-regexp-alist variable, to
   search the assert failure messages for error locations"
  (interactive)
  (progn
    (setq compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist
          (append
           '((caml-assert-failure
              "Assert_failure(\"\\([^,\" \n\t<>]+\\)\", \\([0-9]+\\), \\([0-9]+\\))"
              1 2 3))
           compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist))
    (setq compilation-error-regexp-alist
          (append compilation-error-regexp-alist '(caml-assert-failure)))))

(add-hook 'caml-mode-hook 'caml-change-error-alist-for-assert-failure)
(add-hook 'tuareg-mode-hook 'caml-change-error-alist-for-assert-failure)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes compiling to bytecode gives you more precise stack traces.

1. Make sure you compile with the `-g` option (or use the `debug` tag with ocamlbuild)
2. Compile to bytecode, the stack traces are more precise.
3. Make sure `$OCAMLRUNPARAM` has the `b` option set (see [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual024.html))

`M-x next-error` *will* allow you to follow the stack trace (if you use `caml-mode` from the distribution and at least OCaml 3.11).

Comment: Really ? `M-x next-error` doesn't work on stack trace for me.

Comment: Yes, if you use `caml-mode` from the distribution and at least OCaml 3.11. See [here](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=4628).