# Is it possible to backtrace "failwith" error when executing a binary?

Tags: debugging, ocaml

I develop OCaml programs in Emacs, compile and run the binary in the terminal.

It is possible to backtrace "failwith" error in Emacs like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037763/how-to-trace-failwith-error-in-emacs). But most of the time, "failwith" errors are raised when I execute a binary in the terminal. There is little information except

```
my error message
Fatal error: exception Failure("my error message")
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to backtrace that? I.e., understanding which .ml files are involved in such an execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile with debugging support, you can ask for a backtrace with `OCAMLRUNPARAM=b`.

```
$ cat bt.ml
let g x = failwith "error"

let f x = g x

let main () = f 14

let () = main ()
$ ocamlopt -g -o bt bt.ml
$ OCAMLRUNPARAM=b bt
Fatal error: exception Failure("error")
Raised at file "pervasives.ml", line 30, characters 22-33
Called from file "bt.ml", line 7, characters 9-16
```

In small examples like this, the inliner will make the report a little less useful. In real world programs it's probably more useful.

(But it still might not be as detailed as you'd like.)

Comment: You can also call [`Printexc.record_backtrace true`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Printexc.html#VALrecord_backtrace) at the start of your programs instead of using the environment variable. Need `-g` either way.